# Agregar Fuente a Dompdf Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Buenas tengo un inconveniente, he intentado agregar el tipo de letra al momento de mostrar un pdf, pero no me resulta para el pdf, pero si para cualquier otra sección, muesro el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la fuente es "Poor Richard"

Comment: Creo que lo mejor a utilizar en el caso de la librería DomPDF son fuentes que tengas almacenadas en el storage de tu proyecto. Similar al caso que mostras pero importando los archivos ttf desde tu storage.

Comment: Si te entiendo, pero esta fuente la busqué porque es la que utiliza el cliente en sus formatos de impresión